# Looking for opensource projects for mobile offline trip planning for public transit and walking routes

Tags: software-recommendations, mobile, transit, planning

I'm looking for initiatives pursuing mobile offline trip planning using a combination of public transit data and walking-routes. Thus far, without much success.

[Osmand](http://code.google.com/p/osmand/), seems to be closest, but the part for offline tripplanning isn't completely funded yet. I may contribute, but haven't got a clue about its viability.

I'm looking for any projects pursuing this, or papers (comfortable with reading the academic math-stuff) outlining this. Also roadblocks preventing this (or rather: making quick implementation unlikely), etc. welcome of course.

I'm 'only' looking to do offline trip planning within one city at a time, which obviously brings down complexity lot.

P.S: adapted question from question posted on opentripplanner-forum:
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/opentripplanner-users/m6PGVRBA0eU

Comment: Are you looking for Open Source solutions or are commercial products (aka Nokia Maps API 'offline' mode)

Comment: Looking for open source specifically

Answer (score 2):

[BRouter](http://brouter.de/brouter/) offers many possibilities. It is an [Android application](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=btools.routingapp&hl=en_GB), usable in the OSMand, LocusMap and OruxMaps as well, as the 3rd party offline routing service.

- It offers multiple  [built-in](http://brouter.de/brouter/profiles2/) and [custom profiles](https://github.com/poutnikl/Brouter-profiles/wiki), that are highly sophisticated.
- Current new car profiles are based on kinematic models.
- Hiking profiles consider hiking routes and even SAC alpine route rating.

Answer (score 1):

What about [rrrr](https://github.com/bliksemlabs/rrrr) and [brouter](http://brouter.de/brouter/) (Mainly for bike routing. But supports car and walking. Maybe usefull as an idea for data format). [Web interface](http://brouter.de/brouter-web/) to brouter. Brouter is slower because it is possible to use different profiles for routing on the fly without precalculations. (race bike, moped, doesn't like sidewalks, loves steep hills etc)

I think Rrrr currently support only Public transport.
[About Rrrr](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/opentripplanner-dev/Rrrr/opentripplanner-dev/KsZGE7B-CVQ/KFZ7eZpzOR0J)

I think Rrrr can be used as an OTP sever because API is the same, but it is possible for it to run on a mobile phone. Whole public transport data for Netherlands is 20 MB.

There are some people bridging Rrrrr and OTP. [See post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/opentripplanner-dev/Rrrr/opentripplanner-dev/Wp8tJ5QeJR8/UB8kIIZENNkJ)

So maybe use Rrrr for public transport part and brouter or for other parts. Or maybe just brouter data format which is also quite compact.